# Number staircase - Nested loop

Tags: java, nested-loops

Hello I've been trying to do this in Java:

```
12345678910  
2345678910  
345678910  
45678910  
5678910
```

But I can't seem to do it right. I kept redoing it and still couldn't get how to increase the rows as it go down.

This is my code:

```
class Main {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int n = 0; n <= 4; n++) {
            System.out.print(n + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 9 - n; i++) {
                for (int b = 0; b < 1; b++) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
1012345678  
201234567   
30123456    
4012345     
501234
```

I currently use repl.it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like for each row you want to print the numbers `n` to 10 in one line, with `n` increasing by one for each row.

```
for (int n = 1; n <= 5; ++n) {
    for (int i = n; i <= 10; ++i) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Result:

```
12345678910
2345678910
345678910
45678910
5678910
```

Comment: I was very new to the nested loops and it was very confusing. Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int offset = 0;
    for(int len=10;len>=1;len--)
    {
        for(int n=1;n<=len;n++)
        {
            System.out.print(n+offset);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        offset++;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
12345678910
2345678910
345678910
45678910
5678910
678910
78910
8910
910
10
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid working with tons of single letter variable names (which I found rather confusing as a CS student):

```
String string = String.valueOf(1234567890);
while (!string.startsWith("6")) {
  System.out.println(string);
  string = string.substring(1);
}
```